# Error When Trying To Draw On The PictureBox

Tags: vb.net, draw, picturebox

I have this code. and this code works on button click.

```vb
X1picG00 = Double.Parse(XstrG00) * DrawScale
Y1picG00 = PictureBox1.Height - Double.Parse(YstrG00) * DrawScale

X2picG00 = Double.Parse(XendG00) * DrawScale
Y2picG00 = PictureBox1.Height - Double.Parse(YendG00) * DrawScale

X1picG00 = X1picG00 * Math.Cos(theta) - Y1picG00 * Math.Sin(theta)
Y1picG00 = X1picG00 * Math.Sin(theta) + Y1picG00 * Math.Cos(theta)
X2picG00 = X2picG00 * Math.Cos(theta) - Y2picG00 * Math.Sin(theta)
Y2picG00 = X2picG00 * Math.Sin(theta) + Y2picG00 * Math.Cos(theta)

PictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(Pens.White, Int(X2picG00 + PicBorderX), Int(Y2picG00 + PicBorderY), Int(X1picG00 + PicBorderX), Int(Y1picG00 + PicBorderY))
```

When the program reaches this code:

```vb
PictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(Pens.White, Int(X2picG00 + PicBorderX), Int(Y2picG00 + PicBorderY), Int(X1picG00 + PicBorderX), Int(Y1picG00 + PicBorderY))
```

it shows me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
> Additional information: Overload resolution failed because no Public 'DrawLine' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
>
> ```
> 'Public Sub DrawLine(pen As System.Drawing.Pen, x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, y2 As Integer)':
>     Argument matching parameter 'x1' narrows from 'Double' to 'Integer'.
>     Argument matching parameter 'y1' narrows from 'Double' to 'Integer'.
>     Argument matching parameter 'x2' narrows from 'Double' to 'Integer'.
>     Argument matching parameter 'y2' narrows from 'Double' to 'Integer'.
> 'Public Sub DrawLine(pen As System.Drawing.Pen, x1 As Single, y1 As Single, x2 As Single, y2 As Single)':
>     Argument matching parameter 'x1' narrows from 'Double' to 'Single'.
>     Argument matching parameter 'y1' narrows from 'Double' to 'Single'.
>     Argument matching parameter 'x2' narrows from 'Double' to 'Single'.
>     Argument matching parameter 'y2' narrows from 'Double' to 'Single'.
> ```

I can't understand why this error happened and what is it.

What is this error and how can I fix it ?

Additional information: The variables `XstrG00` and `XendG00` and `YstrG00` and `YendG00` have a value and their values Depend on values of `TextBoxes`.

And the value of `DrawScale` variable is `0.7`.
And the value of `PicBorderX` variable is `70`.
and the value of `PicBorderY` variable is `10`.

Comment: Int() doesn't do what you think it does.  Use CInt() instead.

Comment: First thing, if you're going to call `CreateGraphics` then you MUST dispose the `Graphics` object that you create. Second thing, NEVER call `CreateGraphics`. ALWAYS do all your drawing on the `Paint` event of the control you want to draw on and use the `Graphics` object provided. You should fix that first, then address this issue.